# I am trying to import some custom bootstrap js file but its not working well

Tags: reactjs

./src/Components/js/bootstrap.min.js
  Line 6:    Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 10:    'jQuery' is not defined                                                no-undef
  Line 27:    Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 38:    Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 46:    'jQuery' is not defined                                                no-undef
  Line 53:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 60:    Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 66:    Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 68:    Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 71:    Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 74:    'jQuery' is not defined                                                no-undef
  Line 82:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 86:    Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 88:    Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 95:    Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 96:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 103:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 104:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 107:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 111:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 115:   'jQuery' is not defined                                                no-undef
  Line 124:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 128:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 130:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 195:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 202:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 211:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 214:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 220:   'jQuery' is not defined                                                no-undef
  Line 233:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 237:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 239:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 250:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 252:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 254:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 267:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 269:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 283:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 286:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 296:   'jQuery' is not defined                                                no-undef
  Line 301:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 307:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 313:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 321:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 329:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 340:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 355:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 361:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 366:   'jQuery' is not defined                                                no-undef
  Line 374:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 378:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 382:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 393:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 399:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 408:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 421:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 422:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 425:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 438:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 461:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 464:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 469:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 474:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 483:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 489:   'jQuery' is not defined                                                no-undef
  Line 497:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 501:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 503:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 529:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 572:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 576:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 587:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 593:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 603:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 619:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 625:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 628:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 712:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 715:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 716:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 720:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 723:   'jQuery' is not defined                                                no-undef
  Line 731:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 738:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 749:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 760:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 763:   'jQuery' is not defined                                                no-undef
  Line 767:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 775:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 778:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 786:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 796:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 809:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 812:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 817:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 825:   'jQuery' is not defined                                                no-undef
  Line 832:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 838:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 852:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 853:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 865:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 869:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 872:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 876:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 879:   'jQuery' is not defined                                                no-undef
  Line 887:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 891:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 893:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 921:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 928:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 936:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 942:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 945:   'jQuery' is not defined                                                no-undef[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYO09.png)

Answer (score 0):

You want to import bootstrap and bootstrap uses jQuery and why that it not working

```
function call and instead saw an expression no-unused-expressions Line 220: 'jQuery' is not defined no-undef Line 233:
```

if you want to use bootstrap with react you should use https://react-bootstrap.github.io/ . instead